# Start with OpenCV (Java)

Tags: java, linux, opencv

I download the last version OpenCV (from http://opencv.org/downloads.html for Linux), and installed on ubuntu 12.04 use this commands:

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
cd opencv
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ./
make
make install
```

i create a new project in NetBeans (Java application), and i don`t know why i have that problem:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
```

**package org.opencv.core does not exist**

in python "import cv" is worked!

Please help me resolve this problem! 10Q!!!

Comment: In java you have to provide a library or framework and make it available on the classpath to start referencing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an opencv-2xx.jar under build/bin in your opencv directory.
Just add this jar to your Netbeans project setup.

If you dont have this jar, make sure that your CMAKE output has found ANT and JNI:

```
-- Java:
  -- ant: (path to ant)
  -- JNI: (path to JNI)
  -- Java tests: YES (this one is optional)
```

If CMAKE cant find these resources, make sure ant and JNI are installed. (You can just apt-get install ant).

Make sure your `$JAVA_HOME` is correctly set to your openJDK or OracleJDK dir. (I assume you have a JDK installed!), and is available on the classpath. Run `$JAVA_HOME` from the terminal to check. If not there's plenty of resources that tell you how to do this.

Then `make` and `make install` and you should have the jar.